# How can I display my ggtern plots in my PDF from R Markdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, r-markdown, ggtern

None of my ggtern plots appear in the PDF when I am kniting the R Markdown script I have written.
The R/ggtern script works well.
I have read many posts on the Internet but none of these could help me to fix this issue.
The plots still not appear in the final pdf.
Hown can I fix this?

```
---
title: xxx
subtitle: xxx
author: "xxx"
date: "27/07/2019"
output: pdf_document
---
```

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE} #open chunk
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, error = TRUE, eval = FALSE)
``` #close chunk
````

````
``` #open chunk
{r base3, echo=FALSE}
plot(base3)
``` #close chunk
````

```r
#ggtern 3 zones
points3 <- data.frame(
    rbind(
        c(1,1.000,0.000,0.000),
        c(2,0.500,0.500,0.000),
        c(3,0.500,0.000,0.500),
        c(4,0.500,0.500,0.500),
        c(5,0.000,1.000,0.000),
        c(6,0.000,0.500,0.500),
        c(7,0.000,0.000,1.000)
    )
)
colnames(points3)=c("IDPoint","T","L","R")

#Give each Polygon a number
polygon.labels3 <- data.frame(Label3=c("O","P","N"))
polygon.labels3$IDLabel=1:nrow(polygon.labels3)

#Create a map of polygons to points
polygons3 <- data.frame(
    rbind(
        c(1,1),c(1,2),c(1,4),c(1,3),
        c(2,2),c(2,4),c(2,6),c(2,5),
        c(3,3),c(3,7),c(3,6),c(3,4)
    )
)
polygons3$PointOrder <- 1:nrow(polygons3)
colnames(polygons3)=c("IDLabel","IDPoint","PointOrder")

#Merge the three sets together to create a master set.
df3 <- merge(polygons3,points3)
df3 <- merge(df3,polygon.labels3)
df3 <- df3[order(df3$PointOrder),]

#Determine the Labels Data
Labs3=ddply(df3,"Label3",function(x){c(c(mean(x$T),mean(x$L),mean(x$R)))})
colnames(Labs3)=c("Label","T","L","R")

#Build the final plot
base3 <- ggtern(data=df3,aes(L,T,R)) + 
    geom_polygon(aes(group=Label3),color="black",alpha=0) +
    geom_text(data=Labs3,aes(label=Label),size=3,color="black") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    tern_limits(labels=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),breaks=seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)) +
    theme_clockwise() +
    theme_showarrows() +
    labs(title  = "Test",Tarrow = "% Oui",Larrow = "% Peut-être",Rarrow = "% Non") +
    theme(tern.axis.arrow=element_line(size=1,color="black")) +
    labs(title="Diagramme ternaire 3 zones",T="Oui",L="Peut-être",R="Non")
```

I expect the plots to be displayed in the final pdf.

Here is a screenshot of my .rmd document:

[Screenshot of my .rmd document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNUKH.png)

Comment: `print(base3)`?

Comment: I ran your codes, the plot is showing in my pdf output.

Comment: You should show us a full document.  Yours is probably too large to post here, so delete the parts that aren't necessary to illustrate the problem, and post just a minimal document which shows it.  We can't help if you don't post a reproducible example.

Comment: I have updated my post to be reproducible.

Comment: Your example won't run --- it's not properly formed as an R Markdown document, things are out of order, etc.

Comment: Is it ok now? Markdown is turned off in code blocks...

Comment: Maybe the issue is relative to my r/packages configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I couldn't run your code since you put comments after the chunk options (e.g. deleted `#open chunk`). Then I reordered your code. The plot should be ploted after creating it. And the code to create the plot should be inside the r chunk too. You also need to add `message=FALSE`to the chunk options to avoid having the message from the functions printed. I also had to load the two packages `plyr`and `ggtern`.

The following code worked for me.

````
```
---
title: xxx
subtitle: xxx
author: "xxx"
date: "27/07/2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r base3, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(plyr)
library(ggtern)

#ggtern 3 zones
points3 <- data.frame(
    rbind(
        c(1,1.000,0.000,0.000),
        c(2,0.500,0.500,0.000),
        c(3,0.500,0.000,0.500),
        c(4,0.500,0.500,0.500),
        c(5,0.000,1.000,0.000),
        c(6,0.000,0.500,0.500),
        c(7,0.000,0.000,1.000)
    )
)
colnames(points3)=c("IDPoint","T","L","R")

#Give each Polygon a number
polygon.labels3 <- data.frame(Label3=c("O","P","N"))
polygon.labels3$IDLabel=1:nrow(polygon.labels3)

#Create a map of polygons to points
polygons3 <- data.frame(
    rbind(
        c(1,1),c(1,2),c(1,4),c(1,3),
        c(2,2),c(2,4),c(2,6),c(2,5),
        c(3,3),c(3,7),c(3,6),c(3,4)
    )
)
polygons3$PointOrder <- 1:nrow(polygons3)
colnames(polygons3)=c("IDLabel","IDPoint","PointOrder")

#Merge the three sets together to create a master set.
df3 <- merge(polygons3,points3)
df3 <- merge(df3,polygon.labels3)
df3 <- df3[order(df3$PointOrder),]

#Determine the Labels Data
Labs3=ddply(df3,"Label3",function(x){c(c(mean(x$T),mean(x$L),mean(x$R)))})
colnames(Labs3)=c("Label","T","L","R")

#Build the final plot
base3 <- ggtern(data=df3,aes(L,T,R)) + 
    geom_polygon(aes(group=Label3),color="black",alpha=0) +
    geom_text(data=Labs3,aes(label=Label),size=3,color="black") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    tern_limits(labels=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),breaks=seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)) +
    theme_clockwise() +
    theme_showarrows() +
    labs(title  = "Test",Tarrow = "% Oui",Larrow = "% Peut-être",Rarrow = "% Non") +
    theme(tern.axis.arrow=element_line(size=1,color="black")) +
    labs(title="Diagramme ternaire 3 zones",T="Oui",L="Peut-être",R="Non")

plot(base3)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code works in my .rmd file (in the RStudio console) but the figures are still missing in the pdf output. I wonder if there is an issue somewhere with settings...

Comment: However it works in a R Markdown notebook instead of a R Markdown document. How can it be?
Putting aside this question, thank you Mobody! It works!

Comment: The problem is the `r setup` chunk you included (and I deleted in my answer post). There you set the global options for knited chunks to `eval = FALSE` which means the chunks don't get processed. Delete the chunk or set it to `eval = TRUE`and it should work.

Comment: If this solves your problem it would be nice if you accept my answer.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out after searching answers on the Internet. I accepted your answer. It is recorded but it does not appear publicly because I have less than 15 reputation. Thank you again Mobody.